# How can I eliminate my custom __import__ hook from Python backtraces

Tags: python, import, built-in, traceback

I'm the implementor of [the Lazy Python Reloader](https://github.com/boostpro/lazy_reload), and it's all working wonderfully, except that once I overrode the builtin `__import__` function, I started seeing my replacement in tracebacks whenever there was an error in a module being loaded.  For example, there are two instances of `_real_import` in the following, that are just a distraction—they're just calling through to the builtin import function:

```
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/buildbot-0.8.4_pre_521_gea039fa-py2.6.egg/buildbot/master.py", line 207, in do_load
    exec f in localDict
  File "/Users/dave/src/fossbot-top/master.cfg", line 13, in <module>
    from fossbot import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lazy_reload.py", line 83, in _lazy_reload_import
    m = _real_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/dave/src/fossbot-top/fossbot/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    projects = 'fossbot.projects'
  File "/Users/dave/src/fossbot-top/fossbot/bbot/__init__.py", line 24, in master
    for m in load_submodules(projects):
  File "/Users/dave/src/fossbot-top/fossbot/bbot/util.py", line 30, in load_submodules
    ret.append(_import(parent_module_name+'.'+submodule_name))
  File "/Users/dave/src/fossbot-top/fossbot/bbot/util.py", line 4, in _import
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lazy_reload.py", line 83, in _lazy_reload_import
    m = _real_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/dave/src/fossbot-top/fossbot/projects/el_get.py", line 13, in <module>
    build_procedures=[GitHubElisp('dimitri/el-get')] + 1
```

Does anyone know if there's a way for `lazy_reload` to eliminate those frames from backtraces when they are generated?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* but you also *shouldn't* (even the standard library's `runpy` module leaves itself in the stack trace when the main module is executed via the `-m` switch). When an exception escapes all the way to the top level of a program, it's hard to know in advance exactly which components were at fault (and the fact that reloading is going on has a high chance of being significant).

If you still want to continue down that path, I suggest first taking a look at:
[How can I modify a Python traceback object when raising an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603940/how-can-i-modify-a-python-traceback-object-when-raising-an-exception)

And then at the Jinja2 code which tries to make the templating code produce accurate tracebacks (the link in the answers to the above question is out of date):
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/debug.py

Answer (score 1):

Not without severely hacking the language. I wouldn't recommend this, also because it's usually a bad idea to hide a part of a stack trace. Especially if a part of your module introduces an unexpected error.